# Uncheck all checkboxes if "Other" checkbox is checked and get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So, I have 4 checkboxes:

1. Heating
2. AC
3. Cold Chain
4. Others

The condition is, you can multiple check the three: Heating, AC, and Cold Chain. But when you check on "Other", the three will be unchecked. And when you check again on any of the three, the Other checkbox will be unchecked.

When the Others is checked, a "Please specify" input text will appear.

And in the summary, Looking for solutions in Others - [value]

This is my fiddle

```js
$(document).ready(displayCheckbox);

CountSelectedCB = [];

function displayCheckbox() {       
  $("input:checkbox").change(function() {                 
    selectedCB = [];        
    notSelectedCB = [];                
    CountSelectedCB.length = 0;        
    $("input:checkbox").each(function() {            
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {                
        CountSelectedCB.push($(this).attr("value"));            
      }        
    });                
    $('input[name=solutions]').val(CountSelectedCB).blur();    
  });
}   

$(document).ready(displayRadiobox);

CountSelectedRB = [];

function displayRadiobox() {       
  $("input:radio").change(function() {                 
    selectedRB = [];        
    notSelectedRB = [];                
    CountSelectedRB.length = 0;        
    $("input:radio").each(function() {            
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {                
        CountSelectedRB.push($(this).attr("value"));            
      }        
    });                
    $('input[name=existing]').val(CountSelectedRB).blur();     
  });
}


$('#solutions, #existing').bind('keyup blur', function() {            
  $('#summary').val('You are looking for solutions in ' +                               $('#solutions').val() +                               (' \n') +                              'Are you using an existing customer? ' +                               $('#existing').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> Looking for a solutions in:<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Heating">Heating<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Ac">AC<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Cold Chain">Cold Chain<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Others">Others<br>
</div>
<input name="specify" type="text" id="specify" style="display: none">
<input name="solutions" type="text" id="solutions">


<div><br>Are you an exisiting customer?<br>
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="radio">Yes<br>
  <input type="radio" value="No" name="radio">No
</div>

<input name="existing" type="text" id="existing">
<br><br> Summary:
<br>
<textarea type='text' id="summary"></textarea>
```

Comment: What have you tried to uncheck the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a simple example for you how you can do this using the `prop()` and `siblings()` functions.

Added some classes for better selectors.

```js
$('#wrapper .some-checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.prop('checked')) {
    if ($this.is('.some-others')) {
      $this.siblings().prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {
      $this.siblings('.some-others').prop('checked', false);
    } 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <input class="some-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Heating">Heating<br>
  <input class="some-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Ac">AC<br>
  <input class="some-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Cold Chain">Cold Chain<br>
  <input class="some-checkbox some-others" type="checkbox" value="Others">Others<br>
</div>
```

Comment: I would have accepted this answer, way simpler than the accepted one! I know the accepted one is trying to make the least amount of changes, but it's just a pain to read.

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks for kind words, everyone has his own preferences though. Maybe the OP isn't able to change html.

Comment: I've never got a kiss for an answer before :p Of course, just my 2 cent

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the checkbox `Others` is checked, then uncheck the other checkboxes with `$('<your-checkbox->').prop('checked', false);`

For example:

```js
$(document).ready(displayCheckbox);

CountSelectedCB = [];

function displayCheckbox(){    
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() {          
        selectedCB = [];
        notSelectedCB = [];
        
        CountSelectedCB.length = 0;
        $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                CountSelectedCB.push($(this).attr("value"));
                if ($(this).attr("value") === "Others") {
                  CountSelectedCB = []; // reset result
                 $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
                     if ($(this).attr("value") !== "Others") {
                      $(this).prop('checked', false); // uncheck
                     }
                  });
                  $('input[name=solutions]').hide(); // toggle input
                  $('input[name=specify]').show(); // toggle input
                }
            }
        });
        
        $('input[name=solutions]').val(CountSelectedCB).blur();
    });
}    

$(document).ready(displayRadiobox);

CountSelectedRB = [];

function displayRadiobox(){    
    $("input:radio").change(function() {          
        selectedRB = [];
        notSelectedRB = [];
        
        CountSelectedRB.length = 0;
        $("input:radio").each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                CountSelectedRB.push($(this).attr("value"));
            }
        });
        
        $('input[name=existing]').val(CountSelectedRB).blur(); 
    });
} 


$('#solutions, #existing').bind('keyup blur', function() {
        
    $('#summary').val('You are looking for solutions in ' + 
                             $('#solutions').val() + 
                             (' \n') +
                             'Are you using an existing customer? ' + 
                             $('#existing').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> Looking for a solutions in:<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Heating">Heating<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Ac">AC<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Cold Chain">Cold Chain<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Others">Others<br>
</div>
<input name="specify" type="text" placeholder="Please specify" id="specify" style="display: none">
<input name="solutions" type="text" id="solutions">


<div><br>Are you an exisiting customer?<br>
<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="radio">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" value="No" name="radio">No
</div>

<input name="existing" type="text" id="existing">
<br><br>
Summary:<br>
<textarea type='text' id="summary"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your Fiddle code. Please see this, it will solve your problem.

Here is the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(displayCheckbox);

CountSelectedCB = [];

function displayCheckbox() {       
  $("input:checkbox").change(function() {                 
    selectedCB = [];        
    notSelectedCB = [];
    selectedValue = $(this).attr("value");                
    CountSelectedCB.length = 0;

    if (selectedValue === "Others" && $(this).is(":checked")) {
      uncheckAllCheckBox();
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
      CountSelectedCB.push(selectedValue);
    } else {
      $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("value") === "Others")
          $(this).prop('checked', false);

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          CountSelectedCB.push($(this).attr("value"));
        }
      });
    }                        
    $('input[name=solutions]').val(CountSelectedCB).blur();    
  });
}

function uncheckAllCheckBox() {
  $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
    CountSelectedCB.length = 0;
  });
}

$(document).ready(displayRadiobox);

CountSelectedRB = [];

function displayRadiobox() {       
  $("input:radio").change(function() {                 
    selectedRB = [];        
    notSelectedRB = [];                
    CountSelectedRB.length = 0;        
    $("input:radio").each(function() {            
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {                
        CountSelectedRB.push($(this).attr("value"));            
      }        
    });                
    $('input[name=existing]').val(CountSelectedRB).blur();     
  });
}


$('#solutions, #existing').bind('keyup blur', function() {            
  $('#summary').val('You are looking for solutions in ' +                               $('#solutions').val() +                               (' \n') +                              'Are you using an existing customer? ' +                               $('#existing').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> Looking for a solutions in:<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Heating">Heating<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Ac">AC<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Cold Chain">Cold Chain<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Others">Others<br>
</div>
<input name="specify" type="text" id="specify" style="display: none">
<input name="solutions" type="text" id="solutions">


<div><br>Are you an exisiting customer?<br>
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="radio">Yes<br>
  <input type="radio" value="No" name="radio">No
</div>

<input name="existing" type="text" id="existing">
<br><br> Summary:
<br>
<textarea type='text' id="summary"></textarea>
```

[Updated JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/tfhpuxy4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I modified your **displayCheckbox()**  function. Please try like this. I think your problem will be solved.

```
function displayCheckbox(){    
   $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
     selectedCB = [];
     notSelectedCB = [];
     CountSelectedCB.length = 0;
     if($('input:checkbox[value="Others"]').is(":checked")){
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        CountSelectedCB.length = 0;
        CountSelectedCB.push($(this).attr("value"));
     }else{
        $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           CountSelectedCB.push($(this).attr("value"));
        }
     });
    }
    $('input[name=solutions]').val(CountSelectedCB).blur(); 
 });
}
```

Thank you.